# Postgres query to calculate matching strings

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I have following table:

```
id   description additional_info
123    XYZ          XYD
```

And an array as:

`[{It is known to be XYZ},{It is know to be none},{It is know to be XYD}]`

I need to map both the content in such a way that for every record of table I'm able to define the number of successful match.
The result of the above example will be:

```
id    RID    Matches
1     123    2
```

Only the content at position 0 and 2 match the record's `description`/`additional_info` so `Matches` is 2 in the result.

I am struggling to transform this to a query in Postgres - dynamic SQL to create a `VIEW` in a PL/pgSQL function to be precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's undefined how to deal with array elements that match *both*  `description` and `additional_info` at the same time. I'll assume you want to count that as 1 match.

It's also undefined where `id = 1` comes from in the result.

One way is to [`unnest()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) the array and `LEFT JOIN` the main table to each element on a match on either of the two columns:

```
SELECT 1 AS id, t.id AS "RID", count(a.txt) AS "Matches"
FROM   tbl t
LEFT   JOIN unnest(my_arr) AS a(txt) ON a.txt ~ t.description
                                     OR a.txt ~ t.additional_info
GROUP  BY t.id;
```

I use a regular expression for the match. Special characters like (`.\?`) etc. in the strings to the right have special meaning. You might have to escape those if possible.

---

#### [Addressing your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40353145/postgres-query-to-calculate-matching-strings/40354259?noredirect=1#comment67962926_40354259)

You should have mentioned that you are using a plpgsql function with `EXECUTE`. Probably 2 errors:

1. The variable `array_content` is not visible inside `EXECUTE`, you need to pass the value with a `USING` clause - or concatenate it as string literal in a `CREATE VIEW` statement which does not allow parameters.
2. Missing single quotes around the string `'brand_relevance_calculation_‌​view'`. It's still a string literal before you concatenate it as identifier. You did good to use `format()` with `%I` there.

Demo:

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE
   array_content varchar[]:= '{FREE,DAY}'; 
BEGIN

EXECUTE format('
   CREATE VIEW %I AS
   SELECT id, description, additional_info, name, count(a.text) AS business_objectives
        , multi_city, category IS NOT NULL AS category
   FROM initial_events i
   LEFT JOIN unnest(%L::varchar[]) AS a(text) ON a.text ~ i.description
                                              OR a.text ~ i.additional_info'
 , 'brand_relevance_calculation_‌​view', array_content);

END
$do$;
```

Comment: The query I'm using is : EXECUTE format('CREATE VIEW %I AS SELECT id ,description, additional_info, name, count(a.text) business_objectives, multi_city, category is not null as category FROM initial_events LEFT JOIN unnest(array_content) AS a(text) ON a.text ~ initial_events.description OR a.text ~ initial_events.additional_info',brand_relevance_calculation_view); But it is throwing an exception that column "array_content" doesn't exists inspite I have defined it as: array_content varchar[]:= ARRAY['FREE','DAY'];

Comment: It shows invalid regular expression. Parenthesis not balanced, when I'm querying the sql view that is created.

Comment: @himanshu: Like I mentioned: `Special characters like (.\?) etc. in the strings to the right have special meaning. You might have to escape those if possible.` Or use `LIKE` instead: `('%' || a.text || '%') LIKE i.description` etc. - where only %_\\ have special meaning. Or if you want to match only at the end of the string like in your example:  `('%' || a.text) LIKE i.description`,

Comment: @himanshu: Please start a *new question* for the new question. You can always link to this one for context.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40383958/postgres-complex-queries-in-functions