# Postgres FROM query with one of the column name

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, aggregate-functions, unnest

As follow-up to the previous question:

- [Count matches between multiple columns and words in a nested array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40383958/count-matches-between-multiple-columns-and-words-in-a-nested-array)

I have the following query:

```
SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY t.id) AS id
     , t.id AS "RID"
     , count(DISTINCT a.ord) AS "Matches"
FROM   tbl t
LEFT   JOIN (
   unnest(array_content) WITH ORDINALITY x(elem, ord)
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL
   unnest(string_to_array(elem, ',')) txt
   ) a ON t.description ~ a.txt
       OR t.additional_info ~ a.txt
GROUP  BY t.id;
```

which gives me matches correctly, but now the value for `array_content` needs to be dynamic and that too one of the column value.

Lets say I am using a aggregator function to get the array content within the query as:

```
SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY t.id) AS id
     , t.id AS "RID"
     , array_agg(DISTINCT demo_a.element_demo) as array_values
     , count(DISTINCT a.ord) AS "Matches"
     , count(DISTINCT demo_a.ord) AS "Demo_Matches"
FROM   tbl t
LEFT   JOIN (
   unnest(array_values) WITH ORDINALITY x(elem, ord)
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL
   unnest(string_to_array(elem, ',')) txt
   ) a ON t.description ~ a.txt
       OR t.additional_info ~ a.txt
LEFT JOIN (
   unnest("test1","test2"::varchar[]) WITH ORDINALITY x(element_demo, ord)
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL
   unnest(string_to_array(element_demo, ',')) text
   ) demo_a ON i.name ~ demo_a.text
GROUP  BY t.id;
```

Now what I need is to get the `array_values` column in place of array_content that is defined in the unnest portion. Is it possible?
For now it is giving an exception that column name not defined.

Comment: The added double-unnest for the simple array `{"test","test1"}` makes no sense. A single `unnest()` already unnests all there is to unnest ...

Comment: Also, the proxy CROSS JOIN between your two LEFT JOIN subqueries, is almost certainly wrong. Consider the fishmarket example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464037/two-sql-left-joins-produce-incorrect-result/12464135#12464135

Comment: But @Erwin these 2 left joins serves different purpose.

Comment: Sure, you are still messing up the count. (I am off to bed now ...)

Comment: Is it possible to reference a column name that is defined in select query into a LEFT JOIN as in the above question

Comment: Your question is still unclear to me. Your example still does not make sense. In addition to what I already commented, you reference `i.name`, but there is no `i` in the query. Please fix your question to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

> For now it is giving an exception that column name not defined.

That's because you are using a different column name <strike>`a.obj_element`</strike>. In the subquery, we named the column **`elem`**. (Or did you really mean to use `txt`?) So:

```
SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY t.id) AS id
     , t.id AS "RID"
     , array_agg(DISTINCT a.elem) AS array_values  -- or a.txt?
     , count(DISTINCT a.ord) AS "Matches"
FROM   tbl t
LEFT   JOIN (
   unnest(array_content) WITH ORDINALITY x(elem, ord)
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL
   unnest(string_to_array(elem, ',')) txt
   ) a ON t.description ~ a.txt
       OR t.additional_info ~ a.txt
GROUP  BY t.id;
```

Comment: @SyedAsadAbbasZaidi: Oh, you also renamed the input column `array_content` - by mistake I presume?